# How to install laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, frameworks

I didn't use any framework yet. I am installing Laravel from http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#install-laravel.
we need to install composer before downloading Laravel
When i tried to install composer, it requires php.exe file, whats that? And from where I can download it.
Do I need to install any other software or file to install this?

Comment: If php(.exe) and composer don't sound familiar to you yet, maybe you should start with smaller steps by just reading something about it...

Comment: Stack Overflow isn’t Google. Please familiarise yourself with the fundamentals (the CLI, Composer, PHP) and then come back when you have a _specific_ programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with PHP on windows (I use a Mac). But I'm guessing you will need to use the command prompt to run composer. Put simply, composer is a dependency manager it fetches required libraries that are required by your project (laravel).

Have a read about it here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

With regards to php.exe. Sounds like you don not have PHP installed. Read up here: http://php.net/manual/en/install.php

Alternatively you can try XAMPP: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

If you want to learn about laravel go here:
http://laravel.com/docs

The documentation on these site will explain it better than anyone else can here.

I'd recommend reading up on PHP in more detail if your unsure how Laravel works. Yes it's good, but you'll need to understand PHP before you can jump into it.

http://php.net/